# Correcting dependencies... failed. After upgrade ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, 18.04

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.7 is installed
                Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.7 is installed
                Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.9.5) but 5.5.1-2ubuntu6 is installed
                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-9-5
                Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5
 perl-base : Breaks: debconf (< 1.5.61) but 1.5.58ubuntu2 is installed
 python3 : PreDepends: python3-minimal (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.5.1-3) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is installed
 python3-debconf : Depends: debconf (= 1.5.66ubuntu1) but 1.5.58ubuntu2 is installed
                   Breaks: debconf (< 1.5.64) but 1.5.58ubuntu2 is installed
 python3.5 : Depends: python3.5-minimal (= 3.5.1-10) but 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.13 is installed
             Depends: libpython3.5-stdlib (= 3.5.1-10) but 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.13 is installed
 update-manager : Depends: update-manager-core (= 1:16.04.17) but 1:18.04.11.13 is installed
 update-notifier : Depends: update-notifier-common (= 3.168.19) but 3.192.1.18 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. A question needs a lot more then just a series of errors. A clear  question not just in the title and DETAILS lots of details. Please use the edit function and add them.

Comment: I looked up a package (`libqt5core5a | 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.6  | bionic-updates          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`) chosen at random from your paste, and what it shows is you're still using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS due to *xenial* packages matching what you have installed?   Your description (*largely title*) doesn't match what I found.

Comment: Since you're upgrading from a very old system that's EOL (Ubuntu 16.04), perhaps the best option would be to reinstall a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 system, and restore your important data.